# CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol

Tags: dictionary, clojure, macros, symbols

I need use my macro as functions of map, but I don't know how I can do it. Explain me, please. My macro "get-conj" builds binary functions which consist of conjunction of few variables.

I've already tried put macro in lambda function, but that's not work. Also I checked macro and it's correctly.

```
; this call of map doesn't work.
(map #(get-conj [x0 x1] %) [[1 0] [0 1] [0 0]])

;but just call of get-conj works fine.
(def conjunction (get-conj [x0 x1]  [1 0]) ==> x0 & not(x1)
(conjunction true false) ; ==> true 
(conjunction true true)  ; ==> false

; bit is 1 or 0 value
(defn get-var [bit]
  (if (zero? bit)
    not
    identity))

(defn get-args [n]
  (vec (map #(read-string (s/join [\x %])) (range n))))

(defn mapdef [fns args] (map #(%1 %2) fns args))

;; the macro builds binary functions which consist of 
(defmacro get-conj [args bits] ;conjunction of few variables.
  (let [vars (map get-var bits)]
   `(fn ~args
       (every? identity (mapdef '~vars ~args)))))


I want to get list of binary-functions.
```

Stack trace for:

```
(map #(get-conj [x0 x1] %) [[1 0] [0 1] [0 0]])
 2. Unhandled clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException
       Error compiling *cider-repl clojure/ex1:localhost:40769(clj)* at (1252:16)

             Compiler.java: 7010  clojure.lang.Compiler/analyzeSeq
             Compiler.java: 6773  clojure.lang.Compiler/analyze
             Compiler.java: 6729  clojure.lang.Compiler/analyze
             Compiler.java: 6100  clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser/parse
             Compiler.java: 5460  clojure.lang.Compiler$FnMethod/parse
             Compiler.java: 4022  clojure.lang.Compiler$FnExpr/parse
             Compiler.java: 7001  clojure.lang.Compiler/analyzeSeq
             Compiler.java: 6773  clojure.lang.Compiler/analyze
             Compiler.java: 6729  clojure.lang.Compiler/analyze
             Compiler.java: 3881  clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr/parse
             Compiler.java: 7005  clojure.lang.Compiler/analyzeSeq
             Compiler.java: 6773  clojure.lang.Compiler/analyze
             Compiler.java: 6729  clojure.lang.Compiler/analyze
             Compiler.java: 6100  clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser/parse
             Compiler.java: 5460  clojure.lang.Compiler$FnMethod/parse
             Compiler.java: 4022  clojure.lang.Compiler$FnExpr/parse
             Compiler.java: 7001  clojure.lang.Compiler/analyzeSeq
             Compiler.java: 6773  clojure.lang.Compiler/analyze
             Compiler.java: 7059  clojure.lang.Compiler/eval
             Compiler.java: 7025  clojure.lang.Compiler/eval
                  core.clj: 3206  clojure.core/eval
                  core.clj: 3202  clojure.core/eval
                  main.clj:  243  clojure.main/repl/read-eval-print/fn
                  main.clj:  243  clojure.main/repl/read-eval-print
                  main.clj:  261  clojure.main/repl/fn
                  main.clj:  261  clojure.main/repl
                  main.clj:  177  clojure.main/repl
               RestFn.java:  137  clojure.lang.RestFn/applyTo
                  core.clj:  657  clojure.core/apply
                  core.clj:  652  clojure.core/apply
                regrow.clj:   18  refactor-nrepl.ns.slam.hound.regrow/wrap-clojure-repl/fn
               RestFn.java: 1523  clojure.lang.RestFn/invoke
    interruptible_eval.clj:   79  nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/evaluate
    interruptible_eval.clj:   55  nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/evaluate
    interruptible_eval.clj:  142  nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/interruptible-eval/fn/fn
                  AFn.java:   22  clojure.lang.AFn/run
               session.clj:  171  nrepl.middleware.session/session-exec/main-loop/fn
               session.clj:  170  nrepl.middleware.session/session-exec/main-loop
                  AFn.java:   22  clojure.lang.AFn/run
               Thread.java:  748  java.lang.Thread/run

1. Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
   Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol

                   RT.java:  550  clojure.lang.RT/seqFrom
                   RT.java:  530  clojure.lang.RT/seq
                  core.clj:  137  clojure.core/seq
                  core.clj: 2738  clojure.core/map/fn
              LazySeq.java:   40  clojure.lang.LazySeq/sval
              LazySeq.java:   49  clojure.lang.LazySeq/seq
                   RT.java:  528  clojure.lang.RT/seq
                  core.clj:  137  clojure.core/seq
            core_print.clj:   53  clojure.core/print-sequential
            core_print.clj:  174  clojure.core/fn
            core_print.clj:  174  clojure.core/fn
              MultiFn.java:  233  clojure.lang.MultiFn/invoke
                  core.clj: 3666  clojure.core/pr-on
                  core.clj: 3669  clojure.core/pr
                  core.clj: 3669  clojure.core/pr
                  AFn.java:  154  clojure.lang.AFn/applyToHelper
               RestFn.java:  132  clojure.lang.RestFn/applyTo
                  core.clj:  657  clojure.core/apply
                  core.clj: 4702  clojure.core/pr-str
                  core.clj: 4702  clojure.core/pr-str
               RestFn.java:  408  clojure.lang.RestFn/invoke
                 debug.clj:  188  cider.nrepl.middleware.debug/pr-short
                 debug.clj:  182  cider.nrepl.middleware.debug/pr-short
                 debug.clj:  334  cider.nrepl.middleware.debug/read-debug-command
                 debug.clj:  312  cider.nrepl.middleware.debug/read-debug-command
                 debug.clj:  506  cider.nrepl.middleware.debug/break
                 debug.clj:  488  cider.nrepl.middleware.debug/break
                      REPL:   49  ex1.bfg/eval20195/get-conj
                  AFn.java:  165  clojure.lang.AFn/applyToHelper
                  AFn.java:  144  clojure.lang.AFn/applyTo
                  Var.java:  702  clojure.lang.Var/applyTo
             Compiler.java: 6912  clojure.lang.Compiler/macroexpand1
             Compiler.java: 6989  clojure.lang.Compiler/analyzeSeq
             Compiler.java: 6773  clojure.lang.Compiler/analyze
             Compiler.java: 6729  clojure.lang.Compiler/analyze
             Compiler.java: 6100  clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser/parse
             Compiler.java: 5460  clojure.lang.Compiler$FnMethod/parse
             Compiler.java: 4022  clojure.lang.Compiler$FnExpr/parse
             Compiler.java: 7001  clojure.lang.Compiler/analyzeSeq
             Compiler.java: 6773  clojure.lang.Compiler/analyze
             Compiler.java: 6729  clojure.lang.Compiler/analyze
             Compiler.java: 3881  clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr/parse
             Compiler.java: 7005  clojure.lang.Compiler/analyzeSeq
             Compiler.java: 6773  clojure.lang.Compiler/analyze
             Compiler.java: 6729  clojure.lang.Compiler/analyze
             Compiler.java: 6100  clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser/parse
             Compiler.java: 5460  clojure.lang.Compiler$FnMethod/parse
             Compiler.java: 4022  clojure.lang.Compiler$FnExpr/parse
             Compiler.java: 7001  clojure.lang.Compiler/analyzeSeq
             Compiler.java: 6773  clojure.lang.Compiler/analyze
             Compiler.java: 7059  clojure.lang.Compiler/eval
             Compiler.java: 7025  clojure.lang.Compiler/eval
                  core.clj: 3206  clojure.core/eval
                  core.clj: 3202  clojure.core/eval
                  main.clj:  243  clojure.main/repl/read-eval-print/fn
                  main.clj:  243  clojure.main/repl/read-eval-print
                  main.clj:  261  clojure.main/repl/fn
                  main.clj:  261  clojure.main/repl
                  main.clj:  177  clojure.main/repl
               RestFn.java:  137  clojure.lang.RestFn/applyTo
                  core.clj:  657  clojure.core/apply
                  core.clj:  652  clojure.core/apply
                regrow.clj:   18  refactor-nrepl.ns.slam.hound.regrow/wrap-clojure-repl/fn
               RestFn.java: 1523  clojure.lang.RestFn/invoke
    interruptible_eval.clj:   79  nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/evaluate
    interruptible_eval.clj:   55  nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/evaluate
    interruptible_eval.clj:  142  nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/interruptible-eval/fn/fn
                  AFn.java:   22  clojure.lang.AFn/run
               session.clj:  171  nrepl.middleware.session/session-exec/main-loop/fn
               session.clj:  170  nrepl.middleware.session/session-exec/main-loop
                  AFn.java:   22  clojure.lang.AFn/run
               Thread.java:  748  java.lang.Thread/run
```

Comment: Post the full error with trace, along with example input that you're using.

Comment: Is `bits` being passed as a symbol? Are you sure you need a macro here?

Comment: @Carcigenicate, I added stack trace.  And yes, `bits` is being as a symbol. I want to get list of binary generated functions so I try to write macro. I think I can do it by macros. I understand that macros is calculated early than functions, but I don't know how I should use that.

Comment: Think about what `bits` is given that `get-conj` is a macro. It's not the data that you're expecting.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, I've thought about it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly, you have a set of bits, say `[0 1 0]`. Every bit indicates whether a corresponding argument should be negated or not. Then you want to compute the conjunction of those possibly negated arguments. So if your arguments were `a`, `b` and `c`, with those bits you would like to compute `(and (not a) b (not c))`, right?

As others have already hinted in the comments, you do not need macros to achieve that.

Here is a *function* `get-conj` that as arguments takes the bits sequence and returns a new function that does what I explained above:

```
(defn get-conj [bits]
  (fn [& args]
    {:pre [(= (count bits)
              (count args))]}
    (every? identity (map (fn [bit arg]
                            (if (zero? bit)
                              (not arg) arg))
                          bits args))))
```

Note that the `get-conj` function only takes *one* argument now, which is the `bits`.

And the example code you provided works (with slight modifications):

```
(map get-conj  [[1 0] [0 1] [0 0]])

(def conjunction (get-conj [1 0]))

(assert (conjunction true false))
(assert (not (conjunction true true)))
```

Macros are best used for situation where functions are not enough, such as small syntatic customizations (.e.g. `when`, `->`) or building mini-languages such as [core.async](https://github.com/clojure/core.async) or [Anglican](https://github.com/probprog/anglican) probabilistic programming language.

Comment: Ok, you're right. That means I can realize my algorithm without uses of macros. Thanks a lot! I appreciated your help!

Answer (score 1):

The this is to do with argmuement evaluation problems when #() syntax gets passed a macro symbol... I believe it' fundamentally the same issue that prevents nested reader macros *[ie you can't #(x #(y))]*.  I may not be the best person to have explain it.

For your use case, one workaround is create a function that assembles and evaluates macro calls and pass a partial of *that* to map... this sort of thing is always pretty hacky but here's an example.  You will need to quote symbol arguments.

```lisp
(defn macro-partial [macro-name & supplied-args] 
  (apply partial (comp eval macroexpand list) macro-name supplied-args))

;produces a list of functions created by get-conj.
(map (macro-partial 'get-conj '[x0 x1]) [[1 0] [0 1] [0 0]])

;call like this
(map apply 
      (map (macro-partial 'get-conj '[x0 x1]) [[1 0] [0 1] [0 0]])
      (repeat '(1 2)))
```